# Assigning exit code to a shell local variable

Tags: bash, shell, variable, command-substitution

```
#!/bin/bash
function0()
{
 local t1=$(exit 1)
 echo $t1
}

function0
```

`echo` prints empty value. I expected:

```
1
```

Why doesn't `t1` variable get assigned the exit command's return value -  `1`?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

`local t1=$(exit 1)` tells the shell to:

- run `exit 1` in a subshell;
- store its output (as in, the text it outputs to standard output) in a variable `t1`, local to the function.

It's thus normal that `t1` ends up being empty.

(`$()` is known as [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).)

The exit code is always assigned to `$?`, so you can do

```
function0()
{
  (exit 1)
  echo "$?"
}
```

to get the effect you're looking for. You can of course assign `$?` to another variable:

```
function0()
{
  (exit 1)
  local t1=$?
  echo "$t1"
}
```

Comment: You know, you can always put the return into the pipe, too. `$(trap 'printf "::ERRNO:$?"' 0; # now do whatever however - that trap will ensure the last string written is the last return for the whole substitution context.

Comment: @mikeserv did you miss a backtick? `$(trap 'printf "::ERRNO:$?"' 0; # now do whatever however`

Comment: How about if this was outside a function? I am running bash code in a Makefile and cannot use local. Without local the same problem persists as in the original question.

Comment: @Cheetaiean please ask a new question with details of what you’re trying to do and the problems you’re having.

Comment: Going a step further: I found this question because I wanted to **capture the output** of a command into a **local variable  and use the exit code afterwards**. This can be done by simply declaring it first: `function0(){ local foo; foo=$(echo bar; exit 1); echo "returned $?"; }`

Answer (score 16):

Exit code was stored in [$?](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02) variable. Using [Command Substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) only capture the output, you should use [(...) to create subshell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_01):

```
#!/bin/bash

func() {
  (exit 1)
  local t1=$?
  printf '%d\n' "$t1"
}

func
```

Comment: the point of the assignment `t1=$?` is to use it, no? and wouldn't `$?` get clobbered by the assignment op? I guess I'm asking if it shouldn't be `printf '%d\n' "${t1}"`

Comment: Note that Command Substitution only captures standard out unless redirected differently.

Answer (score 8):

In `bash` this works:

```sh
loc(){  local   "x=$(exit "$1"):$?"
        printf  '$%s:\t%d\n' \
                 x "${x##*:}" \? "$?"
}
```

It has to do with the order of command evaluation and variable assignment. `local` has a return value all its own - and it is the currently executing command, not the command substitution. The reason things like...

```
x=$(exit 1); echo "$?"
```

...can return 1 is because there never is a return in that command except for the subshell run to assign `$x`'s value - so `$?` doesn't get clobbered as  it does in practically every other case in which command substitutions are used.

Anyway, with `local` it *does* get clobbered - but if you catch it at just the right time - which is while the expansions are still being evaluated and *before* `local`'s routines have a chance to clobber it - you can still assign it.

```
unset x; loc 130; echo "${x-\$x is unset}"
```

...prints...

```
$x: 130
$?: 0
$x is unset
```

You should know though that in many shells you cannot rely upon `$?` being set mid-evaluation in that way. In fact, that's probably because those shells do not bother re-evaluating at every possible juncture as perhaps `bash` does - which I would argue is probably better behavior than `bash`'s. Do you really want your interpreter recursively loop-evaluating values which are very likely to be overwritten before ever you have the chance to use them?

Anyway, that's how you can do that.

Answer (score 3):

This does not answer this question exactly, but I think in majority of cases you would make decisions based on the acquired exit code later down the execution stream. If you need to check for success/failure exit code only – it can easily be achieved without storing the code into a variable:

```
if (exit 1); then
  echo "Command succeeded, alles gut"
else
  echo "Oi oi, Huston, we got alles kaputt 'round here"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

@mikeserv's answer is great, and provides explanation for behavior I had discovered but had no idea why it was happening.

I just wanted to add an easy way to avoid `local` eating the exit code of a subshell is to do:

```
val_check_exit() {
   local val=
   val=$(echo "hi"; exit 1)
   local res=$?
   echo "val is ${val}, exit code ${res}"
}
val_check_exit
# outputs:
# val is hi, exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, `$(cmd)` is the Korn shell syntax for command substitution which expands to the output of `cmd`. The Bourne shell (the shell which invented that concept in the late 70s) and C-shell equivalent was `` `cmd` ``.

In the `rc` shell, the syntax was just `` `cmd `` though most of the time, you'd need `` `{more complex cmd} ``.

`rc` was the shell of Plan9 and Research Unix V10, so was the meant-to-be-successor of `sh` for the meant-to-be-successor of Unix though that (unfortunately some would say) never happened even though that's a much better shell on an arguably better system. In `rc`, the equivalent of the Bourne shell's `$?` was `$status` like in `csh` though with a better way to encode exit code and signal termination.

A public domain clone of `rc` was written in the early 90s and that spawned a few derivatives including [`es`](http://wryun.github.io/es-shell/).

I'm mentioning that as in `es`, `` `{cmd ...} `` was command substitution like in `rc`, but `<={cmd ...}` also expands to the exit status of `cmd` rather than its output, and in `es`, an exit status which can also be returned by a function with `return` can be anything including a list, not just a number or a signal name.

So:

```
var = <={ fork {exit 1} }
```

For instance would assign to `$var` the exit status of a subshell running `exit 1`, but you could also do:

```
fn funky {
  return foo 'bar baz'
}

var = <={funky}
echo $var(2)
```

Which would output `bar baz`.

I don't think you can get both the *output* and *return status* of a command though which to me sounds like a serious limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do it in one line and was able to adapt mikeserv's answer and sticking it all in a second subshell:

```
t1=$((exit 1); echo $?);
```

Comment: I would go with `var=$((exit 123); echo $?);`, i.e. with a plain subshell instead of the command substitution, a bit like in cuonglm's answer. Command substitutions exist to capture the output of the command inside, and expand it on the outer command line, and we really don't want to capture any output here. Not that `exit` prints anything, meaning the outer command just disappears without running anything, but it's conceptually "wrong".

Answer (score -1):

Depending why you are trying to just get the exit code you can also just run `if some-command; then echo "Success $?"; else echo "Failure $?"; fi` which doesn't do anything with the output of the command, it just evaluates the exit code of the command run. You can add `or`(`or`$(`around the command and you'll still get the same results. A better example might be`if grep -q 'somestring' somefile; then echo "Found somestring exit code is $?"; else "Did not find somestring exit code is $?"; fi`.

You can also test the return code of a function which can be either an explicit `return 3` or an implied return code which is the result of the last command, in this case you need to be careful that you don't have an `echo` at the end of the function, otherwise it masks/resets the previous exit code.

```
command_last () {
  echo "True is `true`"
  echo "False is `false`"
  false
}
command_last; echo $?
# Outputs:
# True is 0
# False is 1
# 1

echo_last () {
  echo "True is `true`"
  echo "False is `false`"
  false
  # echo'ing literally anything (or nothing) returns true aka exit 0
  echo
}
echo_last; echo $?
# Outputs:
# True is 0
# False is 1
#            # Blank line due to empty echo
# 0
```

Finally a dirty trick since you can't do `VAR=(SOME_COMMAND)` because `VAR=()` is an array definition so you need to `VAR=( $(echo 'Some value') )`.

Comment: All the claimed outputs are wrong, due to the fact that command substitution doesn't give the exit code, which is the whole point of the question. It's not clear what the "dirty trick" has to do with anything.